# How to get the process start time in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How do I get the process start time in PowerShell?

I tried this in the PowerShell prompt:

```
(Get-Process MyProcessName).StartTime.ToString('yyyyMMdd')
```

And this is the error I got:

```
(Get-Process MyProcessName).StartTime.ToString('yyyyMMdd')

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ (Get-Process MyProcessName).StartTime.ToString('yyyyMMdd_h ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

But when I do Get-Process MyProcess, I see my process:

```
> Get-Process MyProcess

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
   2906     132    81136      79132   889           20656 myprocess
```

And when I do 'Get-Date -format 'yyyyMMdd', it returns '20151207', so I think the date format is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
(Get-Date (Get-Process explorer).StartTime).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
```

Answer (score 8):

As a one-liner you could use:

```
Get-Process ProcessName | select starttime
```

Answer (score 2):

Run as admin:

```
Get-Process | select name, starttime | findstr your_process_name_here
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not inputting the **process name** correctly ("MyProcessName" vs. "MyProcess"). You have

```
(Get-Process MyProcessName).StartTime.ToString('yyyyMMdd')
```

But it should be

```
(Get-Process MyProcess).StartTime.ToString('yyyyMMdd')
```

per your examples.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the start time of a specific process use the following substituting "process name" with its name:

```
Get-Process ProcessName | select Name, StartTime
```

or to get all running processes' start times

```
Get-Process | select Name, StartTime
```